# Ruby syntax formatting and highlighting using \snippet command

Tags: doxygen

Doxygen 1.7.6.1 - I am using \snippet command to include Ruby code examples along with html output generated from C++ files, but syntax highlighting for Ruby is being read as C++. Is there a way to specify Ruby syntax highlighting for ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible with doxygen. However, you could parse you code with something like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), which will generate syntax highlighted HTML of your Ruby code. You can then include the HTML in your doxygen documentation. This can be automated by using the `INPUT_FILTER` configuration file option to call Pygments on your Ruby files each time you want to generate your documentation.

Comment: My tests indicate it may not be possible with doxygen using the INPUT_FILTER or FILTER_PATTERNS. The closest I got was generating the html with span and class tags and then doxygen used output to continue processing but span and class tags are visible in browser as text. Also processed all files instead of just *.rb

Comment: Try including the syntax highlighted HTML code using [`\htmlinclude`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdhtmlinclude).